# JSoup selector contains for two elements

Tags: java, select, web-scraping, jsoup

I have a situation where I need to include both of the two possible words from JSoup selector. I have already done it for the first word, but struggle to have some kind of logical OR 'contain another word'. Code I already have:

```
         Iterator<Element> activity = table.select("td[class=xl75], td[class=xl71], td[class=xl73]:contains(word1))").iterator();
```

I have tried to edit it this way:
`Iterator<Element> activity = table.select("td[class=xl75], td[class=xl71], td[class=xl73]:contains(word1):contains(word2)").iterator();`
  but it's not working. Any ideas have to have both of two words included in one selector?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using regex matching for this kinda work.
Where your selector:

> td[class=xl75], td[class=xl71], td[class=xl73]:contains(word1):contains(word2)

Can be rewritten as the following code:

```
td[class=xl75], td[class=xl71], td[class=xl73]:matches((word1)|(word2))
```